# Junit Testing for sum of string method

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

Can anyone give me two failure test cases for this function in java
with specified input and expected result?

```
public int sumOfString(String numbers){    
  if(numbers == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException(); 
  String[] parts = numbers.split(",");
  int sum = 0; 
  for (String string : parts)
  {
    sum += Integer.parseInt(string); 
  } 
  return sum; 
}
```

Here's what I've tried

```
public void testSumOfString() {
    String numbers = "13,4,,5";
    Engine instance = new Engine();
    int expResult = 22;
    int result = instance.sumOfString(numbers);
    assertEquals(expResult, result);
}
public void testSumOfString2() {
    String numbers = "13,A,5";
    Engine instance = new Engine();
    int expResult = 13 + 65 + 5;
    int result = instance.sumOfString(numbers);
    assertEquals(expResult, result);
}
```

Comment: I could; but why should I spent my free time doing your homework?

Comment: You are asking us to give you test cases where your method fails but the method is the only thing that describes the expected behaviour. Sorry but that is an impossible task.

Comment: It's fairly simple to think of MORE THAN 2 cases where your method would fail... I vote to remove this question from SO as it does not respect the way it works around here. We're not your homework monkeys: we help when the help is needed; SO is not a service to find the exact answers for your homework without putting any effort.

Comment: this not a homework for me , i try to find two failure that cause logic error for two hours ago , but still don't find any real solution

Comment: i find two bad test cases using Junit but those test cases cause error not a  unexpected resault

Comment: public void testSumOfString() {
      
        String numbers = "13,4,,5";
        Engine instance = new Engine();
        int expResult =22;
        int result = instance.sumOfString(numbers);
        assertEquals(expResult, result);
       
    }
    
    public void testSumOfString2() {
      
        String numbers = "13,A,5";
        Engine instance = new Engine();
        int expResult =13+65+5;
        int result = instance.sumOfString(numbers);
        assertEquals(expResult, result);
       
    }

Comment: please any help ,,, @KevinAvignon i put 2 hours effort to find solution but still find cases that cause error not a not expected value ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either create your object containing your code or make your class static for testing purposes.

```
//There are your two test cases
//One is when your code tries to accept an empty string
//One is when you're trying to sum alpha characters.
public void testSumOfString() {
       Assert.Equals(new IllegalArgumentException(),MyObject.sumOfString("")); // MyObject is your class
       // the string that I gave to the method can make the method work because it's empty
    Assert.Equals(new NumberFormatException(), MyObject.sumOfString("Assadsdfcdsvc"); 
    }
```

You should update your code to make sure that it the string that the method receives is entirely made of integer values. A good start would be to update your code with the following line

```
  //Update your code with the following 
if(str == null || str.isEmpty()) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
```

Comment: what about i send {"0","A","3"}   , this cause an error ,, is this failure test case i can report it to our Java developer ?

Comment: my exepecting resault : 65+3+0=68

Comment: well in that situation, I don't really get how you would expect such results.. except if you were trying to look at the ASCII value of each characters of the string. More than that, the code only accepts STRINGS. You're sending an array of characters, which is okay. But you should maybe think of converting the method to receive char arrays and then inside the method, convert the array in a string and THEN, try to get the ASCII value of each char and finally make the sum.

Comment: i understood what you say , but really aim trying to understand the  best  software engineering practice in Testing and when i say that my test case is fail or success according to , (Error cause after run time)  and unexpected result  come from bad user input to the function

Comment: well best practices would be to imagine what could go wrong and test it
Such as what I already said and gave you in the response. Refer to this for a good read on the best practices when one is using JUnit http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076265/testing-debugging/junit-best-practices.html